# Is it possible to inherit data annotations in C#?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Can I inherit the "password" data annotation in another class?

```
    public class AccountCredentials : AccountEmail
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "xxx.")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "xxx")]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

The other class:

```
    public class PasswordReset : AccountCredentials
{
    [Required]
    public string resetToken { get; set; }
    **["use the same password annotations here"]**
    public string newPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I have to use different models due to API call's, but like to avoid having to maintain two definitions for the same field. 
Thanks!

Addition: something like

```
[UseAnnotation[AccountCredentials.password]]
public string newPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you define a toally new property - where do you think magically inheritance could evn be possiblöe? That is not inheritance, that would be magic. A compiler magically knowing a new property is related to an old one.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't define it well enough. I rather thought, would be there something like [Use[AccountCredentials.passwordAnnotation]]

Comment: He's referencing that fact the property in `AccountCredentials` is `password`, and you expect the new class `PasswordReset`'s property `newPassword` to inherit data from the `AccountCredential`'s `password` property. So he asked you what made you think inheritance would apply when you're defining an entirely new property in the second class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider [favoring composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and using the [Money Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html).

```
    public class AccountEmail { }

    public class AccountCredentials : AccountEmail
    {
        public Password Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class PasswordReset : AccountCredentials
    {
        [Required]
        public string ResetToken { get; set; }

        public Password NewPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class Password
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "xxx.")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "xxx")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
```

Perhaps it has become a golden hammer for me, but recently I have had a lot of success with this, especially when given the choice between creating a base class or instead taking that shared behavior and encapsulating it in an object. Inheritance can get out of control rather quickly.

Answer (score 2):

In the base class, you can make it `virtual` property, and change it `override` in the derived class. However, it would not inherit attribute, we do a tricky here :

```
public class AccountCredentials : AccountEmail
{
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "xxx.")]
 [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "xxx")]
 public virtual string password { get; set; }
}

public class PasswordReset : AccountCredentials
{
 [Required]
 public string resetToken { get; set; }
 public override string password { get; set; }
}
```