# c# data annotations grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I wish to try and join couple of validators into a same one just to allow me avoid missing validator.

consider,just an example, i have an Id field of type string which i want to validate.
i need to apply couple of validators such as `Required`, `MaxLength`, `MinLength` and some other parsing stuff.
Now, to make it more intersting, i want to add `EmailAddress` validation to all my Id fields, so Im relying on the fact that the validator is already exists so i just want to add it to the validation group.

I have lots of models with Id in them, I want to make some new validator which actually validates couple of things together so it will be easiler and more right to apply validators on the fields.

Couldn't find something about it.

lets see an example: (ignore the fact that it will fail..just to get the idea)

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[StringLength(6)]
[MinLength(5)]
[CustomA]
[CustomB]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

i want to simply write

```
[IdValidator]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

and in somewhere else, IdValidator will validate all of them and more/less whenever i decide to change it.
i want the change to occur in only 1 place.

Comment: Create your own class which inherits those attributes

Comment: i can't inherit more than 1 class, how to you suggest doing that?
prehaps you mean just to create a class with instances of the other validation attributes and 1-by-1 validate?

Comment: I mean you can inherit from `Attribute` and take all the functionality of the Required, MaxLength and MinLength

Comment: @AlexanderDerck just inherit 1 after another until i have a complete chain of classes? like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767350/is-it-possible-to-inherit-data-annotations-in-c

Comment: No, like the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create you own grouped attribute? You can add the attributes you need to the `_attributes` array.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class GroupedValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly ValidationAttribute[] _attributes;

    public GroupedValidationAttribute(int minLength, int maxLength)
    { 
        _attributes = new ValidationAttribute[]
        {
            new RequiredAttribute(),
            new EmailAddressAttribute(),
            new StringLengthAttribute(maxLength),
            new MinLengthAttribute(minLength),
            new CustomAAttribute(),
            new CustomBAttribute()
        };
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return _attributes.All(a => a.IsValid(value));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return _attributes
            .OfType<IClientValidatable>()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetClientValidationRules(metadata, context));
    }
}
```

Comment: @DannyChen agreed, but not what the OP wants

Comment: And doing this means you lose all client side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke added client side validation support :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke now it gathers all the client side rules of all the attributes that support client side validation, and returns those.

Answer (score 3):

You can [create custom data validation attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx) and implement required behavior:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class IdentifierValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinLength { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public IdentifierValidationAttribute(int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        MinLength = minLength;
        MaxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var stringValue = value as string;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
            return false;

        var length = stringValue.Length;

        if(length > MaxLength || length < MinLength)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Also you can make composite attribute like next one:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class IdentifierValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly ValidationAttribute[] attributes;

    public IdentifierValidationAttribute(int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        attributes = new ValidationAttribute[] { new EmailAddressAttribute(), new MinLengthAttribute(minLength), new MaxLengthAttribute(maxLength) };
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return attributes.All(a => a.IsValid(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: that's to specific. it was an example.

Comment: for example, now i want add another validation, lets say [EmailAddress], how can i add it this way?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck of course. but the question is: how to add an already existed validator such as EmailAddress for example

Comment: @OriRefael you can add few data validation attributes to one property: `[EmailAddress, IdentifierValidation] public string StrangeScenario { get; set; }`.

Comment: @VadimMartynov prehaps i wasn't clear enough. i want it to be grouped, not that every Id field i have ill have to write the entire validators again.i know i can just write couple of them together above the field, that's exactly what i want to avoid

Comment: Im gonna upvote, still Syner was 10 secs ahead of you. thats for the help